# How many times can you use a port in settlers of catan?

Tags: catan

The instructions don't say (from what I see) and I need to know for the game.

Answer (score 12):

As many times as you want. Almanac, page 9:

> Example: Nick, the orange player, built a settlement at the ore
>   special harbor. Nick may exchange 2 ore cards for any 1 other
>   Resource Card. He can also trade 4 ore cards for any 2 other cards.

Comment: Just to add on, make sure you're only using the port when it is your turn and during your trading step. In case it needed clarification.

Comment: ... Especially not in the end-of-turn build phase of a 5-6 player game.

Comment: @ChronoD - The "trading phase" concept was only through 3rd edition.  Starting with 4th edition, trading and building may be intermixed, they are no longer separate phases.

Comment: @theamigo I did not know that! Thanks for the update.